# Charge Account Validation Python project

Tags: python-3.x, validation

Design a program that asks the user to enter a charge account number.
The program should determine whether the number is valid by
comparing it to the following list of valid charge account numbers:

```
5658845 4520125 7895122 8777541 8451277
1302850
8080152 4562555 5552012 5050552 7825877
1250255
1005231 6545231 3852085 7576651 7881200
4581002
```

These numbers should be stored in an array. Use the sequential search
algorithm to locate the number entered by the user. If the number is in
the array, the program should display a message indicating the number
is valid. If the number is not in the array, the program should display a
message indicating the number is invalid.

1. Create a data file, valid_numbers.txt, containing the valid charge account numbers as listed in the book.
2. Create a data file, possible_valid numbers, containing a list of possible valid numbers (such as those entered by the user). You will create this file. Include at least 10 numbers, with approximately half valid and half invalid.
3. Compare each charge account number from the file, possible valid numbers, to see if it is listed as a valid number in the file valid_numbers.txt.
4. Create an output file, results.txt which lists the possible valid numbers and the result of validity checking. Create a list of numbers, followed by "VALID", or "INVALID". Space and align neatly.
5. Place your name and student ID at the top of the output file.
6. The output should look similar to:

[What output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB1Of.png)

****Below is my code****

```
ValidNumbers = open("possible_valid numbers.txt", "r")
Account_Number = int(input("Please enter your charge acount number "))
flag = 0

with open('valid_numbers.txt') as f:
    lines =  (f.read().splitlines())

numbers =[int(e.strip()) for e in lines]

for eachelement in numbers :
    if eachelement==Account_Number :
        print ('The number is valid')
        flag =1
        break;

if (flag ==0) :
    print ('The number is invalid')


ValidNumbers.close()
```

I don't know how to complete part 4

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit off from the homework assignment, I suggest that you use search engines to research code sniplets on how to complete the tasks of the assignment:

Step 1 -- this is a manual process, no code required

Step 2 -- this is a manual process, no code required

Step 3 -- you need to write code to:

- read file created in Step 1
- read file created in Step 2
- then compare the two, keep the valid checks

Step 4 -- you need to:

- create a new file
- write a header (which is specified in Step 5)
- write the results from Step 3

Step 5 -- actually done in Step 4

Step 6 -- this is a manual step, no code required

Good Luck !